# Align Bootstrap Tags with Text in List

Tags: django, text-align, bootstrap-5

How can I align the right side of the tag with the left side of the text (image attached shows the problem) so it looks like this:

```
superlongtagname | text1
  shortertagname | text2
     tinytagname | text3
```

Here's what mine looks like now:

[image]

Here is my template code (looping through a list of Django objects):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="badge bg-{{ t.get_color_display }}">
          {{ t.name }}
        </span>
        {{ rn.entry_text }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried alignment utilities (`align-end`), floating (on both the `li` and the `span`), etc, and nothing seems to work.

**UPDATE**
I was able to get this working with [@Michael H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6664400/michael-h)'s help. I was trying avoid tables, but after fiddling with it a while, it's not that bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a table instead of the `<ul>` tag:

```html
    <table class="table table-borderless">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-end">
            <span class="badge bg-success">
              added
            </span>
          </td>
          <td class="w-100">Added something</td>
        </tr>
        <!--Other items-->
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

[Here's my jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tL5jq3yr/)

The result will look like this: [image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I considered this approach previously, as this is how I've done these alignments in the past. But using tables has drawbacks so I was hoping something so obvious would have a more elegant solution. I'll consider your solution either way.